# Why my styles are breaking when I try to apply a clear fix method?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a page here is the skeleton inside of the body tag:

```
<div id="site-nav-container">
    <nav id="page-navigation"></nav>
</div>
<header id="site-header"></header>
<div class="content-container clearFix">
    <section id="blog-post-sum"></section>
    <aside id="site-sidebar"></aside>
</div>
<footer id="site-footer"></footer>
```

So here is what I am facing: For styling purpose I had to float the section with ***"blog-post-sum"*** id to the left and the float the aside with the id ***"site-sidebar"*** to the right. To prevent margin collapse I wrapped the section and the aside tag in a div container and gave it a ***"clearFix"*** class so that I could use a clear-fix method. The method I used is as follows:

```
.clearFix:before, .clearFix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearFix:after {
    clear: both;
}
<!--[if  lt IE 8]>
/*For IE < 8(trigger hasLayout)*/
.clearFix {
    zoom: 1;
}
<![endif]-->
```

It works like a charm but the problem is if I try to put this method in the begging of my css file then the styling rules right after the clear Fix method breaks. Just like that! So please help me to find out the solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Just a heads up, code snippets are for runnable code. If you just paste your code 4 spaces in then it will show up in a code-block without the 'snippet' parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid comments in your CSS:

```
<!--[if  lt IE 8]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

This is a comment for an HTML file. It won't work in your CSS file.

You can either move that entire comment chunk into your HTML file (don't recommend) or consider using another way to target less-than ie8 browsers. Here's how [boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) used to handle this until recently (in your HTML file, replace your `<html>` tag with this):

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9 ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

This adds a class to the HTML tag indicating the browser. Then you can target it in your CSS like this:

```
.lt-ie8 .clearFix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh KG :-D That explains a lot and also solved the problem! Cheers!!